# Limit the number of calling specific endpoint dynamically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm using JakartaEE 8 to implement JAX-RS restful API on Payara server. now I need to limit calling specific endpoint (download file) over **IP** with min and max number dynamically (everyone can download with 1-4 active connection).

this specific endpoint has **public access**, but it could be called by authenticated/authorized user too, and if authorized user call that endpoint, limit number of connection should change to other number (authorized user with same IP can download with 8 connection).

*I implement a filter and check/insert in database on every request, but I think is not a good approach!*

What is the best/alternative solution?

thanks

Comment: I think this solution is not so bad as long as you make less than 1000 database queries per second. The only thing I could suggest is load data for authorized users at login

Comment: thanks, so I do the same @donquih0te